# C# Expression Tree with Ignore Case or tolower

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, expression-trees

I want to create expression.Equal() with ignore case. 
Sample code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.BrandCode))
{
    MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(parmExpression, "BrandCode");
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(request.BrandCode, typeof(string));
    expbrandCode = Expression.Equal(me, constant);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.CountryCode))
{
    MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(parmExpression, "CountryCode");
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(request.CountryCode, typeof(string));
    expCountryCode = Expression.Equal(me, constant);
}

var finalexpression = Expression.AndAlso(expbrandCode, expCountryCode);
```

Pass the final expression into a method which accepts the expression.

I tried to create a Methodinfo for Tolower, passed it in Expression.Equal() and that didn't work.

Any guidence would be helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I need to pass this expression in a where clause

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`string.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx), like:

```
var expbrandCode = Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Equals", null, me, constant, Expression.Constant(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Note that if you want to use the expression with Entity Framework or similar orms then it becomes complex... Not sure if they support translating that `string.Equals()` overload.